# Only display a character if the ISNULL has a valid entry

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, concatenation, data-presentation

In SQL Server, what I'm looking at doing is concatenating two fields together.  So, for example, I have this layout:

```
Col1         Col2
Building A   Room 101
Building B   Room 2A
Building C   Room 301
Building D
Building E   Room 200
```

And I want to concatenate them like:

```
Building A-Room 101
Building B-Room 2A
Building C-Room 301
```

What is happening when it comes to `Building D` is I get:

`Building D-`

which is awful.  I thought that I could do `ISNULL([Col1] + '-', '')` but this will always display the `-` character.  Is there a way to only add the `-` value if `[Col2]` has a value without using a `CASE` statement?  Or am I going about this in the wrong approach?

Answer (score -1):

I think your test needs to evaluate `Col2`, not `Col1`.  Try this

```
SELECT [Col1] + ISNULL('-' + [Col2], '')
```

Comment: Surely this will never be `null` because you are putting in the `-` character

Comment: Did you try it?  When I tested, it worked as expected.  Null concatenated to a non-null should give you null.  You may need to check the ANSI NULL settings.

Comment: I did try it and I got the `-`